# Using a value from string in the same form which is in a switch block

Tags: c#, string, winforms

sorry for the possibly simple question, but I could not find a solution.

I have e.G. a string in a switch, I would like to use the string with its value in a other block, but I get following message "The name 'getFileName' does not exist in the current context".

Here's the code:

```
switch (ofd.ShowDialog())
{
case DialogResult.OK:
string getFileName = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
labelStatus.Text += getFileName;
break;
}
```

How can I use the string *getFileName* in a other block with its value (in the same form in different blocks or similar)?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { try { Process.Start(getFileName); } catch { //... } }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Set `getFileName` outside the `switch`. `string getFileName = "";`

Comment: Well you can declare it outside the switch block - but you'll need to give it some value to use for when you *don't* match that case.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { try { Process.Start(getFileName); } catch { //... } }`

get an empty value, or so. I build a switch, the user can choose the exe file and the value from the exe will stored in the _getFileName_ but I need the value in a other block.

Comment: Edit: it seems to work, the string is complete outside from blocks, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside of both the functions so it can be accessed by either function.

```
private string getFileName = '';

protected override void SomeFunction(){
    switch (ofd.ShowDialog())
    {
        case DialogResult.OK:
             getFileName = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
             labelStatus.Text += getFileName;
             break;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
try { 
     Process.Start(getFileName); 
    } catch { //... } 
}
```

I suggest you search YouTube for c#.net variable scope to better understand when an where a variable can be accessed :)